# LAYOUT ENCOURAGES ACCIDENTAL CLICKS - INTERSTITIAL ADS:

Tags: android, layout, admob, interstitial

Please any one help Now my app has disable by admob due to wrong interstitial code as

> "Interstitial ads that load unexpectedly while a user is viewing the
>   app’s content".

what to do? Please some one correct me...

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

    public class a2 extends AppCompatActivity {

        AdView mAdView;
        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
        WebView WebViewWithCSS;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_a2);

            WebViewWithCSS = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

            WebSettings webSetting = WebViewWithCSS.getSettings();
            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            WebViewWithCSS.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            WebViewWithCSS.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.html");

            mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

            // set the ad unit ID
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

            adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .build();

            // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    showInterstitial();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.pause();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.resume();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.destroy();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }


        private void showInterstitial() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Interstitials should show in between screens of app. This way the user expects something changes and opening ad won't make him click it accidently (which he should not do according to admob rules). In here you load ad and show it when it gets loaded. Actually you should load the ad ealier and show it when it's ready AND the time is right. I believe it is said so in the tutorials. If this is your first screen you can always keep user in some sort of waiting screen before the ad loads.

Comment: Could you share the code for it?

Comment: Everyone is saying about right time. I am really curious what do they mean by right time? If i load the data, show the ad and onAdClose / onAdFailed showing the page data, would it be right time?

Answer (score 2):

from admobs own [guidelines](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287)

"A common issue is that even though you may intend for the ad to load in between page content, the ad itself appears shortly after a new page of content has loaded due to carrier latency."

Your code shows the interstitial when it has finished loading - this won't give the user any warning so they'll be in the middle of looking at the webview and suddenly the interstitial appears. Pre-load it and show it at a natural break.

Your code calls showInterstitial() in onAdLoaded() - it needs to call mInterstitialAd.loadAd() in advance of the ad being needed, and set a flag to say that it is present. It can then call the showInterstitial() before loading the webview and show the web view when the interstitial ad is dismissed

Comment: Could you please correct the and share with us please

Answer (score 2):

Ads are disabled on my app after a couple of warnings, even I followed AdMob guidelines. I found the following key points in my research:

- Show Interstitial between pages
- Show Interstitial when a game level is completed
- Avoid accidental clicks
- Show on **RIGHT TIME**

The only issue I had was with right time. When is the right time for loading Interstitial? It all depends on you but in my case, an Interstitial was loading and showing after few seconds activity. This was happening because of slow internet connection. What basically happens is that activity shows and a user start interaction but Interstitial is not loaded yet. But the Interstitial loads and shows in the mid of interaction which causes an accidental click - which is against the policy.

Here are some corrective measures I took for my app:

- Limit showing an ad for a person
- Check if an ad is loaded and then display it while leaving an activity

For the first point, I used AdMob settings to limit the **Frequency Cap** to limit displaying an ad for a person. I show one ad in five minutes.

> Frequency capping: Limits the number of times ads are shown to the same
>   person per minute, per hour, or per day.
>   [image: Google AdMob]

And I also used counter in an activity to show an ad when a user visits an activity a couple of times.

For the second point, I show an ad when a user goes back to the previous screen.

In the onCreate() method:

```
counter = sharedPreferences.getInt(AD_COUNT, 0);
editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

if(2 == counter) {
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_unitID));
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
} else {
    editor.putInt(AD_COUNT, sharedPreferences.getInt(AD_COUNT, 0) + 1).apply();
}
```

And onBackPressed() method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (2 == counter && interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        interstitialAd.show();

        //Reset the counter
        editor.putInt(AD_COUNT, sharedPreferences.getInt(AD_COUNT, 0)).apply();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```